# Why my websocket cannot connect I have protocol error with amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, nestjs

I am running a docker instance in EC2 and I create a chat with nest/websockets, locally the chat works fine but when I deployed I have this erro api url  **net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**,In my load balancer I opened the port and add it to secure rules, but still having the same issue. My docker compose look like this [docker-compose.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6nnR.png)my https port its the 443,  the dockerfile [dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56wQw.png)  and my websocket gateaway [Websocket gateaway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRC19.png)
Load balancer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7dHU.png)
any idea can help
Thanks

I expect my websocket can connect to the EC2 in my aws.
EC2  I opened ports and add it to secure rules

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSL termination configured on your load balancer (which is common for HTTPS traffic), the load balancer will handle SSL decryption and forward unencrypted traffic to the EC2 instance. In this case, the WebSocket server inside the Docker container should be listening on a regular HTTP port (e.g., 80) instead of HTTPS (443). The load balancer will handle the SSL handshake and decryption.